# phonegap for iOS :the audio doesn't work correctly

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

phonegap ios:
On running the app the audio and ads doesn't work ,But after pressing the home button and reopening it everything works fine.
How can I fix that?

Comment: was the screen locked when the audio was playing.

Comment: The audio and the ads start working after pressing the home button and reopening the app,OR after locking the screen and unlocking it.
it plays audio only when the app is opened

Comment: If you look in the phone gap documentation they have mention how to handle this issue in iOS.  http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_media_media.md.html playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked: Pass in this option to the play method to specify whether you want to allow playback when the screen is locked. If set to true (the default value), the state of the hardware mute button is ignored, e.g.:

var myMedia = new Media("http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_-_rockGuitar.mp3")
myMedia.play({ playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked : false })

Comment: solution helped to solve the problem.